# Use regex to find out if a string is just a single repeated character

Tags: php, regex, repeat

I'm writing a PHP script and I'm at this point where I need to know if a string consists of one character that's just repeated. The character is even a specific one: it's `z`.

For example, I want to match `"z"`, `"zzz"` or `"zzzzzzzzz"` but not `"zaz"` or `"aaa"`.

This is probably a simple regex question, but I have no idea how to do this. Anyone?

Comment: You really have *no* idea at all?

Comment: Gumbo: I got as far as `[z]+` but that seems to match any string with more than one consecutive `z` in it.

Comment: But it’s a good point to start from. You could have asked a more specific question based on that like “`[z]+` matches any string that just contains one or more `z`; how to match a string that consists of `z` only?”

Comment: This question is making me sleepy…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match it with `^z*$` : begin (^), any amount of z's (z*), end ($)

Comment: Depends on the result you want for an empty string.

Comment: It should be `^zz+$` since for it to be repeated it must happen >=2 times.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified: one `"z"` should match too. (edited the post to clarify)

Answer (score 2):

`^zz+$`

..... la la 15 characters

Comment: sometimes the character limit goes against brevity.

Comment: @PP: That’s ok, `z` can match too. I just want all strings that consists of only `z`, so including `z` itself.

Answer (score 1):

If regex scares you - you can use a function like Harmen proposed or something like:

```
$string = 'zzzzzzzzz';
$check = str_repeat('z', strlen($string));
var_dump($check == $string); // dumps bool(true)

$string = 'zzzzAAAzzz';
$check = str_repeat('z', strlen($string));
var_dump($check == $string); // dumps bool(false)
```

Comment: Even easier: `str_replace('z', '', $string) == ''`

Comment: Thanks Mikhail and JoostK. I especially like JoostK's solution :)

Comment: Sneaky joostK :) Then we can shrink it even further to `!str_replace('z','',$string)`

Comment: Yes will do, however I don't like the negation since it's harder to imagine what's going on exactly. And for the record, PHP has the function `str_repeat`, to avoid the empty string to start with in `str_pad`.

Comment: Noted and updated. Just noticed another solution: `substr_count($string', 'z') == strlen($string)`

Comment: And I just figured why I don't like it. Imagine a string as `'zzzz0z'`, would become `'0'` en then `!'0' === TRUE`. Always be careful with loose comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

No regex needed. Harness the power of PHP's arrays:

```
count(array_unique(str_split($string)))==1
```

Comment: aren't arrays more processor intensive than a regex search?

Comment: @Keng: Even if it were slower and if we're not talking about 10,000 iterations, the difference will be insignificant

Answer (score 1):

When I'm checking to see if a string is just the same character repeating, I do this:

```
if (strlen(count_chars($string, 3)) = 1) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom function like this:

```
function oneLetter($str){

  for($i=1; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
    if($str[i] != $str[i-1]) return false;
  }

  return true;

}
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but it didn’t seem like a very good solution…

Comment: Even for the harder problem, `/^(.)\1*$/` or `/^(?:(.)\1*)?$/` would work fine.